# Grab ID from post from plugin and use it to create an object

Tags: plugins, posts, wp-head

I want to create an object and set ID for this object

like

```
$p = new Product(87);
```

I have this code within a plugin and I want to grab the ID of the custom post being showed:

```
function getPostId(){ 
        global $wp_query;
        global $pid;
        $pid = $wp_query->post->ID;      
        echo 'pid=' . $pid; //returns 87
} 
add_action('wp_head','getPostId');

//I want to get the $pid here.
echo 'pid=' . $pid; //returns null
```

Now I want to do:

```
$p = new Product($pid);
$p->setABigTomatoOnYourHead();
```

I can't just use `get_the_ID()`, `global $post` etc because it's not accesible.

Basically all I do is grab the ID from the custom post being viewed. In my plugin I then want to create a new object based on that ID.

**UPDATE**
"here" is in the same file that classes are created in the main file of the plugin:

like

```
class Product {
}

$x = new Product($id); //here
```

Comment: Where is "here"?

Comment: @s_ha_dum  - updated question...

Comment: You need to add your code when the variables are available. Hook into 'init' or later before attempting to use the query id.

Answer (score 1):

> I have this code within a plugin and I want to grab the ID of the
>   custom post being showed:

...

> "here" is in the same file that classes are created in the main file
>   of the plugin:
>
> ```
> class Product {
> }
>
> $x = new Product($id); //here
> ```

You can't do that. The "custom post being showed" isn't being showed on your plugin page, and your action won't fire on the backend at all. You will have to create your object inside the `wp_head` hook or some other front-end hook -- something like:

```
function getPostId(){ 
    global $wp_query;
    global $x; // bad variable name
    $x = new Product($wp_query->post->ID);
} 
add_action('wp_head','getPostId');
```

It is very possible that you could rewrite the class to avoid some or all of that `global` mess.

If you need the ID of a page on the backend you are going to have to find another way to identify the page. You simply can't hook to an an action that doesn't fire to find the ID of a page that isn't loading.